# Django - User session display user data

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I would like to display the list of entries where the user.username foreignKey is egal to session username. I want to display the specific data related to a session user only.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='e-mail')
    date_signed = models.DateTimeField('date signed')

class ezMap(models.Model):
    map_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import *
from ezmapping.models import *

def listEzMap(request):
    #really not sure how to do it...
    username = request.session['username']
    user_list = ezMap.objects.get(map_name = username)
    return render_to_response("map_list.html", {'user_list': user_list})
```

map_list.html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="list">
  <h2> Map list </h2>
    {% for object in user_list %}
<li>{{ object.map_name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you for your help with this!

Comment: django has a built in User model.  It has all authentication, session management built in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

views.py:

```
def listEzMap(request):
    user_list = ezMap.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render_to_response("map_list.html", {'user_list': user_list})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always access the logged in user from request as `user = request.user`, then use that user information to take decisions on user basis:

```
user = request.user
user_list = ezMap.objects.get(map_name = user.username)
```

You should check [django authtication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) system as mentioned by `dm03514` in comment.